# scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__' when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I want to make my project to an exe file, however, when I open `main.exe` after pyinstaller's processing, there is an error in CMD.

My environment is Win10, python3.6.2, using PyQt5 as GUI, scapy3k to sniff packets.

Or there is an alternative way to turn my project into exe?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 103, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "networkx\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "networkx\linalg\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "networkx\linalg\algebraicconnectivity.py", line 105, in <module>
File "networkx\linalg\algebraicconnectivity.py", line 122, in _LUSolver
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\sparse\linalg\matfuncs.py", line 19, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\special\__init__.py", line 648, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\special\_ellip_harm.py", line 7, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
module = loader.load_module(fullname)
File "_ellip_harm_2.pyx", line 7, in init scipy.special._ellip_harm_2
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\integrate\_bvp.py", line 11, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\optimize\__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 28, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\optimize\_trustregion_krylov.py", line 2, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 631, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "scipy\optimize\_trlib\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
File "d:\python36\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.4.dev0+ab8fd9753-py3.6.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 714, in load_module
module = loader.load_module(fullname)
File "stringsource", line 103, in init scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib
AttributeError: type object 'scipy.optimize._trlib._trlib.array' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

The source code of my program is here:
[The Github link to my program](https://github.com/AntiSomnus/sniffer)

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Throwing a long code and your whole github directory does not make for easy bug fixing.    See: https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1953

I used cython and pyinstaller with no issues.

There is cxfreeze but I do not recommend it.  It's a older, buggier version of pyinstaller without the updating feature of pyupdater.

Comment: What do you mean? You successfully turned my project to exe? I'm afraid after updating lxml I still have the same problem. And cxfreeze is not working either on my computer.

Comment: @user6456568 Not sure how i can help. That's a lot of problems.  I also never said your project, but i have gotten cython to work with pyinstaller.  Good luck.

Comment: In my case I was getting the same error (but with scipy) and @user9045698 pointed me to the correct thread: after updating scipy (which I assume uses a newer cython) I no longer get the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the main python code, type the following code:

```
from scipy import optimize
```

Then run pyinstaller to generate the exe file.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this particular thing but what I see so far is a bunch function OP can use when importing your suggested `from scipy import optimize`. Should OP not add a few addition lines to do something or is it only needed for the compiler/pyinstaller? Furthermore: welcome to SO. Thanks for posting an answer. Please read the info about [how to ask a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Enjoy SO ;-)